# How to correctly use the Contains method on an ArrayList of controls?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have an arraylist of asp.net controls (textbox, etc).

I need to check if a control exists in the arraylist already before adding a new one.  How can I do this, since the .Contains doesn't seem to work properly on the ArrayList of controls.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
Private Sub AddControl(ByVal ctrl As Control)
Dim al As ArrayList = DirectCast(Session("MyControls"), ArrayList)

If Not al.Contains(ctrl) Then
 al.Add(ctrl)
 Session("MyControls") = al
End Sub
```

Comment: can give you my answer in c# since you have set c# tag on the Q?

Comment: Yes, that's fine...c# or VB. Thanks!

Comment: In what way doesn't `Contains` work? I tried a sample bit of code and it seemed to work fine for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maybe this will work:

```
object[] items = al.ToArray();

bool result = items.Any(c => c.Id == ctrl.Id );

if ( !result )
{
   al.Add(ctrl);
   Session["MyControls"] = al;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use [Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) since you don't have to actually count the items?

Comment: I think I may not have been clear in my description.  My array list can have multiple TextBoxes, just that the Ids must be unique.

Comment: Edit it again, I hope this will help